# pyspark - how to cross validate several ML algorithms

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-ml

i want to be able to choose the best fit algorithm with it's best params .
how can i do it in one go , without creating few pipelines for each algorithm , and without doing checks in the cross validation for params that are not relevant for specific algorithm ?
i.e i want to check how  logistic regression perform against randomforest.
my code is :

```
    lr = LogisticRegression().setFamily("multinomial")
    # Chain indexer and tree in a Pipeline
    pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[labelIndexer,labelIndexer2, assembler, lr , labelconverter])

    paramGrid = ParamGridBuilder() \
        .addGrid(lr.regParam, [0.1, 0.3, 0.01]) \
        .addGrid(lr.elasticNetParam, [0.1, 0.8, 0.01]) \
        .addGrid(lr.maxIter, [10, 20, 25]) \
        .build()

    crossval = CrossValidator(estimator=pipeline,
                              estimatorParamMaps=paramGrid,
                              evaluator=RegressionEvaluator(),
                              numFolds=2)  # use 3+ folds in practice

    # Train model.  This also runs the indexer.
    model = crossval.fit(trainingData)
```

Comment: Did you find the answer? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a quick and dirty workaround in Python/Pyspark. It is a bit primitive (it doesn't have a corresponding Scala class) and I think it lacks the save/load capabilities but it might be a starting point for your case. Eventually it might become a new functionality in Spark it would be nice to have.

The idea is to have a special pipeline stage that acts as a switch between different objects, and maintains a dictionary to refer to them with strings. The user can enable one or another by name. They can be either Estimators, Transformers or mix both - the user is responsible for keeping the coherence in the pipeline (doing things that make sense, at her own risk). The parameter with the name of the enabled stage can be included in the grid to be cross-validated.

```
from pyspark.ml.wrapper import JavaEstimator
from pyspark.ml.base import Estimator, Transformer, Param, Params, TypeConverters

class PipelineStageChooser(JavaEstimator):
    
    selectedStage = Param(Params._dummy(), "selectedStage", "key of the selected stage in the dict",
                      typeConverter=TypeConverters.toString)

    stagesDict = None
    _paramMap = {}

    def __init__(self, stagesDict, selectedStage):
        super(PipelineStageChooser, self).__init__()
        self.stagesDict = stagesDict
        if selectedStage not in self.stagesDict.keys():
            raise KeyError("selected stage {0} not found in stagesDict".format(selectedStage)) 

        if isinstance(self.stagesDict[selectedStage], Transformer):       
            self.fittedSelectedStage = self.stagesDict[selectedStage]

        for stage in stagesDict.values():
            if not (isinstance(stage, Estimator) or isinstance(stage, Transformer)):
                raise TypeError("Cannot recognize a pipeline stage of type %s." % type(stage))     
        
        self._set(selectedStage=selectedStage)
        self._java_obj = None

    def fit(self, dataset, params=None): 
        selectedStage_str = self.getOrDefault(self.selectedStage)
        if isinstance(self.stagesDict[selectedStage_str], Estimator):
            return self.stagesDict[selectedStage_str].fit(dataset, params = params)
        elif isinstance(self.stagesDict[selectedStage_str], Transformer):
            return self.stagesDict[selectedStage_str]
```

Use example:

```
count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer() # set params
hashing_tf = HashingTF() # set params
chooser = PipelineStageChooser(stagesDict={"count_vectorizer": count_vectorizer, 
                                           "hashing_tf": hashing_tf},
                               selectedStage="count_vectorizer")

pipeline = Pipeline(stages = [chooser])

# Test which among CountVectorizer or HashingTF works better to create features 
# Could be used as well to decide between different ML algorithms
paramGrid = ParamGridBuilder() \
    .addGrid(chooser.selectedStage, ["count_vectorizer", "hashing_tf"])\
    .build()
```